# Flutter Android build failed for task ':auto_orientation:verifyReleaseResources'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When I run the command `flutter build apk --release` then i face the following **issue with auto_orientation**.

In my pubspec.yaml file I have the latest version included `auto_orientation: ^1.0.5`.

Btw. when I run the project with `flutter run` everything **works fine**.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                

* What went wrong:                                                      
Execution failed for task ':auto_orientation:verifyReleaseResources'.   
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  /Users/johannes/flutter_projects/udare/app/build/auto_orientation/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:236: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /Users/johannes/flutter_projects/udare/app/build/auto_orientation/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:237: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

Flutter doctor:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, v1.12.15-pre.29, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G95, locale
    en-DE)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.2.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.4)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.40.2)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@GreenTigerEye, this could be due to AndroidX incompatibility. You could try directly using the source code of `auto_orientation` package or try few options mentioned [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32595) for a similar issue.

Comment: Thanks :) i had to put the compileSdkVersion to 28 for some plugins like it is described in the resource you have linked